# I need an element like TextSwitcher in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

Hi guys i just used TextSwitcher but this isn't the element that i exactly want. Firstly there shouldn't be any buttons, it can be slided with finger, also not like ScrollView. One slide for one text change. I hope i could explain my problem properly.

Comment: Do you have any example you can provide? Like if you have seen such feature in an app or if you can provide a gif/video link to your requirement.

Comment: it's like when you slide songs on spotify, but i have to slide texts